# UIAlertView inside UIAlertView

Tags: objective-c, uialertview

I am new to `iOS` programming and I have a question regarding `UIAlertViews` as the topic suggests.

I have a button to delete records in a `SQLite DB`. This buttons calls a `UIAlertview` to give the user a few different options when deleting records.

```
- (IBAction)deleteFunction:(id)sender {
UIAlertView *delChoice = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select from below." message:@"WARNING!:You are about to remove records. This is irreversible." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Delete Completed jobs",@"Delete All records",@"Select items to delete.", nil];
[delChoice show];
}
```

Here is the next method

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
NSString *title =[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
if([title isEqualToString:@"Delete All records"]){
    [database executeUpdate:@"delete from issues"];

    if([database lastErrorCode]!=NULL){
        UIAlertView *unconfirm = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Failure!" message:@"Something went wrong. Try one more time." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [unconfirm show];
    }else {
        UIAlertView *confirm = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Success!" message:@"All records have been removed." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [confirm show];
    }
}
```

This isn't the complete method. My question is, inside the nested uialertview's (unconfirm and confirm), if i decide to add "otherButtonTitles" How do I respond to them?
Do i do the same thing I've been doing in the same main method?

Also if there is a better way to do this I would appreciate the pointers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I can think of doing it would be like

```
- (IBAction)deleteFunction:(id)sender 
{
    UIAlertView *delChoice = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select from below." 
                                                        message:@"WARNING!:You are about to remove records. This is irreversible." 
                                                       delegate:self 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"Delete Completed jobs",@"Delete All records",@"Select items to delete.", nil];

    [delChoice setTag:1]; // Setting the tag can help determine which view has come into a method call.
    [delChoice show];

}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{

    switch([alertView tag]) {
        case 1:
              NSString *title =[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
              if([title isEqualToString:@"Delete All records"]){
                  [database executeUpdate:@"delete from issues"];

                  if([database lastErrorCode]!=NULL){
                      UIAlertView *unconfirm = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failure!" 
                                                                     message:@"Something went wrong. Try one more time." 
                                                                    delegate:self 
                                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" 
                                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
                      [unconfirm setTag:2];
                      [unconfirm show];
                   } else {
                      UIAlertView *confirm = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success!" 
                                                                     message:@"All records have been removed." 
                                                                    delegate:self 
                                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" 
                                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
                     [confirm setTag:3];
                     [confirm show];
                   }
             }
         break;
         case 2:
                // Do what you wish here for if UIAlertView has tag 2
                break;
         case 3:
                // Do what you wish here for if UIAlertView has tag 3
                break;
         default:
                // If you have any other UIAlertViews that have some basic default functionality you can do that here.
                break;
     }
}
```

So what is happening here? We are setting each of our `UIAlertViews` a tag from that when we press a button on any of the `UIAlertViews` we will be taken into this `alertView: clickedButtonAtIndex:` method. So we use the `UIAlertViews` tag that we have set to select the right case in a `switch statement`. We take the `UIAlertViews` tag and select the correct case so if `([alertView tag] == 1)` then we would do case `1` and so on for the other `UIAlertViews`. We then have a default case so if you decided that you needed another `UIAlertView` you could ever add another case so `case 3` or you could you the default case to handle the default functionality. Don't forget your breaks at the end of each case if you miss the `break;` at the end the statement will continue into which ever case is below that one. Hope it helps if you have any questions please just comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can add more buttons in your UIAlertview but use `tag` property to each alertview to distinguish from one another. Like-

```
UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"FlurtR" message:ERROR_INTERNET delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
alert.tag=11;
[alert show];
```

and when you have to evaluate you have pressed the OK or cancel button use this

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (alertView.tag==11 && buttonIndex==0)
    {
        [self hideIndicator];
        checkForAlertView=0;
    }
}
```

You can also define `tag` property inside the  `- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex` method in any `UIAlertView` where you will
check the alert tag and button index without any problem.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
 // Yes you can do with this same thing but i suggest you to compare with ButtonIndex instead of string value like

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
   if (buttonIndex == 0) {
       NSLog(@"Clicked button index 0");
      // Add the action here
   } else {
       NSLog(@"Clicked button index other than 0");
      // Add another action here
   }
}
```

Comment: soz, this answer doesnt really answer my question =P

Answer (score 0):

if you have more than one UIAlertViews you should first distinguish between the UIAlertViews.

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
if([alertView.title isEqualToString:@"Select from below."]){
NSString *title =[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
if([title isEqualToString:@"Delete All records"]){
    [database executeUpdate:@"delete from issues"];

    if([database lastErrorCode]!=NULL){
        UIAlertView *unconfirm = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Failure!" message:@"Something went wrong. Try one more time." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [unconfirm show];
    }else {
        UIAlertView *confirm = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success!" message:@"All records have been removed." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [confirm show];
    }
}
else if([alertView.title isEqualToString:@"Failure!"])
{
  // do your stuff for the failure alertView
}
```

}